# Offer to open url in app instead of IE in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app that displays news stories for a publication. If a user opens a story on their phone in IE, I would like to offer an option to open it in the newsreader app instead. Is it possible to hook into IE somehow to do this? Or perhaps display a link on the website that the phone knows how to translate into an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to hook your application to IE. The OS only provides this functionality to some special apps (ie. YouTube). Launching apps from IE is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) control for doing this.

Since you're displaying news stories I'm assuming your app is going to download these from some website. To do this you can create a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and use the [`DownloadStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method to fetch the story. In the [`DownloadStringCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event handler load the web page using `WebClient.NavigateToString`.

Comment: I already am downloading the data and displaying the stories in my app. I'm just trying to make it easy for users to quickly switch from viewing a story in IE to viewing it in my app.

Comment: @Rosarch Sorry, misunderstood your question. You could just have 2 buttons on the ApplicationBar, one for viewing in-app and another for opening in IE. I've seen a couple of other apps that do this.